# JButton Icon a little bit off

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I tried to program a small TicTacToe and gave the buttons I used for the game an icon depending on which player marked that button (you know, the traditional cross and circle).

Now, when I check my buttons "in game", the icons are a little bit off; there is a small (maybe 10 px big) gap between the icon and the button border.

I already tried this but it didn't work:

```
button.setHorizontalAlignement(SwingConstants.RIGHT)
```

Example Code:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175,175));   //Note: Image is also 175x175
button.addActionListener(new MyOnClickListener());

...

class MyOnClickListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        ImageIcon myIcon = new ImageIcon("source");
        button.setEnabled(false);
        button.setIcon(myIcon);
        button.setDisabledIcon(myIcon);
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUyCe.png)

[image]

See that little white margin to the right? This is what i don't want. I want the icon to fill the button completely.
Here's the icon:
[Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAU9n.png)

[image]

Comment: Provide some code so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: Welcome to SO! Afraid to help we'll need you to provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue, and screenshots to show what it looks like at present and what you want it to look like.

Comment: Hope it is clearer now!

Comment: Can you add a raw image of the icon, without the button? Easier to reproduce that way.

Comment: Actually, it seems like I can not reproduce your problem, using a solid-black icon on a red button. The button is showing a one-pixel border around the icon, but otherwise the image is centered and fills the button.

Comment: 1) `button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175,175));   //Note: Image is also 175x175` Note, don't force a size. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: .. 3) Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) for tips on configuring the button to be the same size as the icon it is displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove extraneous space, set the border of the button to `null`. This might require (in some PLAFs) changing the look of the icon itself to indicate focus, hover, pressed etc.

In this screenshot, the middle button in the right hand column is focused, while the  mouse is hovering over the middle button in the bottom row.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.net.URL;

public class TicTacToeButtons {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    private String path = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAU9n.png";
    private BufferedImage image;
    Image transparentImage;

    private JButton getButton(int i) {
        Image img = (i%2==0 ? image : transparentImage);
        JButton b = new JButton(new ImageIcon(img));
        b.setBorder(null);
        return b;
    }

    TicTacToeButtons() {
        try {
            initUI();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initUI() throws Exception {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        image = ImageIO.read(new URL(path));
        transparentImage = new BufferedImage(
                image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));
        for (int ii=0; ii<9; ii++) {
            ui.add(getButton(ii));
        }
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                TicTacToeButtons o = new TicTacToeButtons();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"In my case, the button does not have an icon right until after being clicked."* It is possible to 'pre fill' the button with a *transparent* image of the same size. See edited code & screen shot for details.